# CakePHP - Pulling associated model details into edit screen

Tags: cakephp

This is my model relationships:

```
expenseClaim hasMany expenses
expenses HABTM expenseCodes
expenseCodes HABTM expenses
```

In my expensesClaim edit() function I pull in all associated expenses (one on each row) within a form so the user can edit.

On each row (expense) I have a drop down so they can select the expenseCode (same as the expensesClaim add() function).

However on the edit view the expenses code previously selected by the user has not been populated from the database...

How can I pull in both the expenseClaim, expenses and expensive code into the same page ?

I've tried:

```
$this->ExpenseClaim->recursive = 2;
```

With no success.

ExpenseClaim Model:

```
    <?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * ExpenseClaim Model
 *
 * @property User $User
 * @property ClaimStatus $ClaimStatus
 * @property Expense $Expense
 */
class ExpenseClaim extends AppModel {

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'id';

/**
 * Model validation
 *
 */

    public $validate = array(
        'user_id' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Error - the user_id is missing',
            ),
        ),
        'approved' => array(
            'boolean' => array(
                'rule' => array('boolean'),
                'message' => 'Error - approved should be boolean',
            ),
        ),
        'date_submitted' => array(
            'datetime' => array(
                'rule' => array('datetime'),
                'message' => 'Error - date submitted cannot be blank',
            ),
        ),
    );


    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'ClaimStatus' => array(
            'className' => 'ClaimStatus',
            'foreignKey' => 'claim_status_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Expense' => array(
            'className' => 'Expense',
            'foreignKey' => 'expense_claim_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: can you show us what the model looks like ?

Comment: Added the ExpenseClaim model. However, looking at the baked expense edit view (no good to me as users can only edit expenses via expenseClaim edit()) they seem to use a hidden input field next to the select: <input type="hidden" name="data[ExpenseCode][ExpenseCode]" value="" id="ExpenseCodeExpenseCode_">. I cant seem to replicate this with formhelper in the expensesClaim view despite trying. I wonder if this is the reason?

Comment: show the expensesClaim edit() method, it does not correctly set request->data which is used to prefill form with data

Comment: Ceeram - I think your right as I've just hit an issue with edit creating new records and not saving changes. Going to do a bit more digging and post as a new question if I cant solve.